# Is it possible to import my own SVG into Canva

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, cs6, canva

I'm trying to figure out a way how to import my own vector SVG graphic to Canva.

I've tried numerous tutorials on creating SVG files from Adobe Illustrator, I've tried numerous Ai to SVG convertors, but when importing into Canva, I get the same old error .. sorry cannot ..

Is there a way to import SVG to Canva? Is it even possible?

Is there a set of particular settings for the SVG file?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://support.canva.com/create-your-design/uploads/photo-file-requirements/

Comment: Thanks Joonas, done all my settings as per the help doc, but still getting the same error.

Comment: I would try to make a simple rectangle with a fill and see if that works. If it does, there's likely some issue you overlooked in your other svg files. If even that doesn't work, I'd contact an a support.

Comment: Hey Joonas, good idea, but still getting the same result unfortunately. The error says: We were unable to upload your file as it's either not compatible with Canva or corrupted. I'm trying to use the same settings from this tut: http://thenewcode.com/823/SVG-Export-Settings-For-Adobe-Illustrator

Comment: I have also tried 'Presentation Atributes' instead of 'Style Attributes' in the CSS properties settings. In fact I think I've probably tried it all.

Comment: Contacted support now, so waiting to hear anything back.

Answer (score 0):

So I've run into the same problem. What you need to do, first of all is check this website out:
https://support.canva.com/create-your-design/uploads/photo-file-requirements/#svg

Than when exporting from illustrator make sure you use the "save as" option not export. Because in export you will not find those options (at least I didn't).

When I saved it with "export" option, it didn't let me, only when I used "save as" and used the settings from the link.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE**: *Please* read **[tour]** to get a sense of our community. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to answer it. We're *typically* looking for long-ish answers that provide explanation and context; we prefer answers *don't* just give either a *one-line* or a link-only answer: details in the answer body help protect against link-erosion; remember, this should be just as much for *future* searchers as for *this* asker. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to better fit our guidelines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

css properties have to be set to 'presentation'

Comment: Hey Sammie, welcome to GDSE. Would you be so kind as to [edit] your answer to include a bit more info? How can you set these properties, which menu item or what workflow are you using, can you show it on a screenshot? Thanks. Enjoy the site, keep contributing and check out the [tour] if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. And the problem was the layer inside csv was named. After deleting the name it worked. Do not ask me why :)

I have figured out since I hot two one color logos, one worked, other not. So I have compared whats wrong, different.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change image location from linked to embed. Only thing that worked for me